# Cant dispatch action without mutation

Tags: javascript, function, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I cant dispatch an action with vuex without committing a mutation.

I imported the usual mapActions etc. like always (bare in mind all works correctly, I can execute mutations, getters, get my state all via mapMutations, mapActions etc., I can even dispatch actions IF I include a commit).

For the most simple thing I created an action in my dedicated store/actions.js.

```
repeatWord(data) {
console.log(data)
}
```

on my vue component I defined it like following:

```
methods: {
...mapActions({
repeatWord: 'repeatWord'
)}
```

and I call it via:

```
this.repeatWord('test')
```

Should work, right? Well, it doesnt.
What i get in the console is {getters: {...}, state: {...}, rootGetters: {...}, dispatch: f, commit: f,...}

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html):

> Action handlers receive a context object which exposes the same set of methods/properties on the store instance

That comes in as the first argument.  The second argument is your passed data.  So define your action like this:

```js
repeatWord(context, data) {
   console.log(data)
}
```

Often you'll see that `context` argument destructured like:

```js
repeatWord({ commit, dispatch }, data) {
   console.log(data)
}
```